# D3.js "TypeError: groupData is undefined" in nested json data linechart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, linechart

I need help while parsing a line chart with d3.js

First I want to show my JSON file:

```
[
{
    "Paket": [
        {
            "farbe": "#ff0000",
            "Koordinaten": [
                {
                    "paketaufenthaltsort": " ",
                    "y": "5",
                    "x": "0"
                },
                {
                    "paketaufenthaltsort": "469/31 A 1; A 3; A 4",
                    "y": "5",
                    "x": "150"
                },
                {
                    "paketaufenthaltsort": "469/31 A 1; A 3; A 4",
                    "y": "0",
                    "x": "150"
                }
            ],
            "Paketnummer": "11000005"
        }
    ],
    "offset": "5",
    "referenzzeitraum": "1440"
}
]
```

so now I want to have a linechart with

X-Axis: paketaufenthaltsort
y-Axis: y
with the color : farbe

So I tried the following:

```
 d3.select("body").select("svg").remove();

  var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 100,
  left: 50
   }, width = 1150 - margin.left - margin.right, height = 600 - margin.top
      - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundPoints([0, width], 0);

  var y = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var ordinalScale = d3.scale.ordinal();

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",
      width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height",
      height + margin.top + margin.bottom).attr("id", "svg").append("g")
      .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   var line = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
return (x(d.paketaufenthaltsort));
 }).y(function(d) {
return y(d.y);
  });

    var data;
   d3.json("/fls2/rest/paketVerlaufChart", function(error, json) {

if (error) return console.warn("Error: " + error);
data = json;

var orte;
var pakete;
var koordinaten;

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Paket.forEach(function(p) {
    orte = p.Koordinaten.map(function(k) {
      return k.paketaufenthaltsort;
    });
  });
});

pakete = data.map(function(d) {
  return d.Paket;
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
  koordinaten = d.Paket.map(function(p) {
    return p.Koordinaten;
  });
});

x.domain(orte);

y.domain([d3.min(data, function(c) {
  return d3.min(c.Paket, function(v) {
    return d3.min(v.Koordinaten, function(l) {
      return l.y;
    });
  });
}), d3.max(data, function(c) {
  return d3.max(c.Paket, function(v) {
    return d3.max(v.Koordinaten, function(l) {
      return l.y;
    });
  });
}), ]);

svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform",
        "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);

svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis);

var graphen = svg.selectAll(".graphen").data(koordinaten).enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "graphen");
graphen.attr("stroke", function(d) {
  console.log(d.x);
  return (d.farbe);
}).data(pakete.Koordinaten).enter().append("path").attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          console.log(d);
          return line(d);
        });


  });
```

If I debug, there is a "TypeError: groupData is undefined"
So I need farbe from pakete and the koordinaten from pakete.Koordinaten

So here is the JSFIddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/thomas190393/r0pdsp9s/1/

Whats wrong?

Please help me.

Comment: At which line of code you get the error? It would be better if you add a jsFiddle.

Comment: so here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas190393/r0pdsp9s/1/

Comment: The error being shown in the browser console  is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.  Use `data(pakete[0][0].Koordinaten)` instead of `.data(pakete.Koordinaten)` will fix that issue.

Comment: thank you. but it isn't working correctly right now. If I replace it the way yout told me, there is no more graph. I refreshed the jsfiddle. please help me one more time

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas190393/r0pdsp9s/